# Ionic v4 giving blank screen in physical device

Tags: android, ionic4

Versions:

Ionic 4, type=Angular, cordova v7.0.0

When I am trying to run command: ionic cordova run android 
my application runs perfectly in emulator (device version 7.1 API 25) but when I am trying to install the app to my physical device which has version 4.4.2 (API 19) I saw blank screen.

In my config.xml file I see that:

```
<engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3" />
```

What can I do?

Additional details from debug with android studio:

```
02/22 13:30:32: Launching android
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of C:\Ionic\testApp\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-debug.apk
$ adb shell am force-stop io.ionic.starter
$ adb shell am start -n "io.ionic.starter/io.ionic.starter.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Connecting to io.ionic.starter
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
V/Provider/Settings: get setting for user 0 by user 0 so skipping cache
    invalidate [system]: current 297 != cached 0
D/ActivityThread: hoder:android.app.IActivityManager$ContentProviderHolder@42ed8968,provider,holder.Provider:android.content.ContentProviderProxy@42ed90e0
V/Provider/Settings: from db cache, name = anr_debugging_mechanism , value = 1
D/asset: AssetManager-->addDefaultAssets CIP path not exsit!
W/ActivityThread: Application io.ionic.starter is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/dalvikvm: Debugger is active
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000a (code=1), thread 18688 (o.ionic.starter)
```

Comment: Very hard to say but my first guess is https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/platform/Platform/#ready

Comment: What am I looking for? How this would helped me?

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling these imports in `polyfills.ts`:

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Works for me :)